# Is it possible to uninstall SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I installed SQL Server with Reporting Services package by mistake and I will never have a requirement to use the Reporting Services part.

Is it possible to uninstall Reporting Services (and anything else that would have been included/installed because of Reporting Services)?

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Programs and Features`, find the `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)` entry, select `Uninstall/Change`, and then select `Remove` in the window that pops up.

You select the instance you are working with:
[image]

Then check `Reporting Services` you installed:
[image]

Comment: If SSRS has been installed alongside an instance of sql server, is there any true benefit to uninstalling ssrs if it isn't being used? Or should I just leave it be? This is on a production sql server.

Comment: If it is disabled only thing to deal with is it still has to be patched. Security standards would require the "app" to be patched because it is installed.

Comment: what would you recommend? remove or just leave it?

Comment: If you know it is not going to be used... Remove it.